# JQGrid loses records on column sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid

I am having an issue with a JQGrid losing records when a column sort occurs. For example, if there are 400 records, when the sort occurs, the record count drops to 20.

```
    $("#grdCaseFind").jqGrid({
  datatype: "local",
  height: 250,
  colNames:['SeqNo', 'Report Title', 'Location', 'Status', 'Date', 'Officer Name', 'Incident No.'],
  colModel:[
    {name:'SeqNo',index:'SeqNo', hidden:true},
    {name:'RepTitle',index:'RepTitle', align:"center", width:200},
    {name:'CaseAddr',index:'CaseAddr', align:"center", width:200},
    {name:'RepStatus',index:'RepStatus', align:"center", width:50},
    {name:'CaseBeginDate',index:'CaseBeginDate', width:70, align:"center"},
    {name:'RepOfficerName',index:'RepOfficerName', width:100, align:"center"},
    {name:'IncidentNo',index:'IncidentNo', width:80, align:"center"},
  ],
  multiselect: false,
  caption: "",
  onSelectRow: function (rowid, status) {
    if (status === false) {
      $(this).resetSelection();
      $("#btnOpen").attr("disabled", true);
     } else {
      $("#btnOpen").attr("disabled", false);
      $("#CaseSelectedIndex").val($("#grdCaseFind").getCell(rowid, "SeqNo"))
     }
  },
  ondblClickRow: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
    document.getElementById("btnOpen").click();
  },
  onSortCol: function (index, iCol, sortoder) {
    $("#btnOpen").attr("disabled", true);
  }
});
```

The data is filled from a JSON array stored on the form itself.

```
    grdCaseFindData = strFindResult.grdCaseFind;
    $(grdCaseFindData).each(function (i, e) {
      $("#grdCaseFind").addRowData(i + 1, e);
      $("#grdCaseFind").attr("rowNum", i + 1);
    });
```

I ran into this issue before, and by counting the records and setting the "rowNum" attribute, the issue was corrected. In my other grids, the only difference is that I am loading the records via a call to the server, which returns a JSON array. Any ideas of why this grid is not behaving like the others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disregard the question. Apparently there is an issue with setting the rowNum attribute dynamically after the grid is initialized. The only work around I found to this was to either

```
rowNum: -1
```

Which only works in earlier versions of JQGrid, or

```
rowNum: 9007199254740992
```

Which is the maxInt size, an astronomically high number that is not likely to be reached.

If anyone knows a more elegant and current solution, please correct my answer.